# Redirect from normal activity to TabActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabactivity

I have a tabactivity in which i have 5 tabs using activitygroup.I am going to a normal actvity via Intent from a tabactivity which name is Myprofile and normal activity is not declear in tab. so my problem is how to redirect to tabactivity from normal activity which in not declear in tab.
please help..thanxx in advance

Comment: cannot understand your question pls be clear and post some code (your efforts) towards the problem.

Comment: I think he's saying that he's at a tab activity and has started a new activity. After finishing the new activity the old tab activity does not have the previously selected tab selected anymore.